# Permissions not supporting device

Tags: android, permissions, google-play, android-manifest

I have published an app to Google Play in alpha, during testing I discovered some devices required an additional permissions for ACCESS_WIFI_STATE so I added it and all was well.

Upon adding it to Google Play and attemping to download it on the device which required the permission (in this case it was a Galaxy Tab 2) I get the following error:

```
Previously active APKs supported more devices than those in the draft configuration. Some devices will not receive upgrades.
Devices currently running version 1 are no longer supported by the current configuration. Such devices will not receive upgrades. 
API levels in range 14+ and 
Release track containing any of [ALPHA] and 
Screen layouts containing any of [small, normal, large, xlarge] and 
Native platforms containing any of [armeabi, armeabi-v7a, mips, x86] and 
Features containing all of [android.hardware.BLUETOOTH, android.hardware.CAMERA, android.hardware.camera.AUTOFOCUS, android.hardware.screen.PORTRAIT, android.hardware.TOUCHSCREEN] but excluding any of [android.hardware.WIFI]
```

My Manifest is like so:

```
    <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING"/>
```

Could anyone explain why this error is appearing?  The only device I see it on is the exact one I needed to add the given permission to.

Old Manifest was as so:

```
   <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING"/>
```

Comment: Please add the corresponding section of your old manifest as well.

Comment: Done, I had only added <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />

Answer (score 0):

From the [uses-permission documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-permission-element.html):

> In some cases, the permissions that you request through
>    can affect how your application is filtered by
>   Google Play.
>
> If you request a hardware-related permission - `CAMERA`, for example -
>   Google Play assumes that your application requires the underlying
>   hardware feature and filters the application from devices that do not
>   offer it.
>
> To control filtering, always explicitly declare hardware features in
>   `<uses-feature>` elements, rather than relying on Google Play to
>   "discover" the requirements in `<uses-permission>` elements. Then, if
>   you want to disable filtering for a particular feature, you can add a
>   `android:required="false"` attribute to the  declaration.
>
> For a list of permissions that imply hardware features, see the
>   documentation for the `<uses-feature>` element.

So you can add

`<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.wifi" android:required="false" />`

like described [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html#permissions-features).

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a try.  But I was more curious as to why the device which specifically told me (via the logs) to add the WIFI permission is not saying it does not support it, or at least Play is saying that.